# How do I simluate an Input for a single Node in Godot?

Tags: game-development, godot

I have a node for which I want to trigger input events at specific times programmatically. I have timers to trigger the event, but I am unsure how to trigger the input. I checked the docs and only found solutions to simulate input events for the entire game and not just a single node.

Edit: I noticed that I can call the Node._input function. Is it safe to do this or will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to call `_input`, `_gui_input`, et.al. The `Node`s should not react to this (e.g. a `Button` won't get pressed). And it would not affect the result the `Node` gets from `Input`. *If you run into any exception, that is a bug, please report at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues*

You can, of course, have `_input`, `_gui_input`, et.al. limit themselves to identifying which `InputEvent` they get and calling a different method to actually react to it... This allows you to also call that other method or methods externally at your convinience.

Most - if not all - of the interactions with `Node`s have other ways to archive them, for example you can press a `Button` by setting its `button_pressed` property to `true`. *If you need to change the state of a `Control` in a way that is not available, consider writing a proposal at https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues.*

And if you need the `Node` signals, go ahead and `emit` them from your own code (note: a different `Object` can trigger the signals, e.g. `$Node.pressed.emit()`).

And, finally, if you need to get a different result form `Input`, I suggest to create an script that wraps `Input` so you can [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) it only for the `Node` you want.